# Quickblox Javascript SDK Integration

Tags: javascript, quickblox

I am using JavaScript SDK for group chat. I have registered users into QuickBlox with whom a user can chat.I have created session and token using API calls and referred the JavaScript SDK sample chat demo. There was no feature of user login. It asked directly username and group name to log in on landing page. So when I only pass the username, it is creating a new user with random login instead of authenticating existing user,and the created dialog is different and it wouldn't create a group chat.

I have utilized following Javascript SDK

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk

Looking forward for appropriate solution

Answer (score 0):

We have used special logic for our samples: one browser can create only one user, by the next steps just the user's full_name will be updated. If log out is be, the user will be deleted. And then a next one user can be creating.
It helps us to not creating too much users on backend side.